# centering plus signs inside circles

Tags: html, css

I have the following

```css
.circle {
  font-size: 4.42em;
  font-weight: 300;
  width: 106px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*color: white;*/
  line-height: 94px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 106px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8.73px 0.27px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.39);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">+</div>
```

Unfortunately, whenever I set the line-height to equal to height of the circle, the + sign inside the circle doesn't align in the middle. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It depends on the baseline of the font being used. Use Arial and the the `+` appears vertically centred. With the default font on mac it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use of below style:

```css
.circle
{
    font-size: 4.42em;
    font-weight: 300;
    width: 106px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 106px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8.73px 0.27px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.39);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">+</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `line-height` to match `height`.

```css
.circle {
  font-size: 4.42em;
  font-weight: 300;
  width: 106px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  line-height: 106px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 106px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8.73px 0.27px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.39);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">+</div>
```

Comment: _"Unfortunately, whenever I set the line-height to equal to height of the circle, the + sign inside the circle doesn't align in the middle"_. Check your example on a Mac and it won't work.

Comment: I suppose that depends on the font being used.

Answer (score 0):

Set your `line-height` the same `height` and you don't need `vertical-align` but you do need `text-align:center;`

```css
.circle {
  font-size: 4.42em;
  font-weight: 300;
  width: 106px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*color: white;*/
  line-height: 106px;
  height: 106px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8.73px 0.27px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.39);
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align:center;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">+</div>
```

Comment: When I use line-height: 106px, it aligns the plus sign at the bottom of the circle

Comment: @BrownKL then you must have some other styles as the snippet works for me in Chrome, FF and IE

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea just add `text-align: center;` and change `line-height: 94px;` to `line-height: 106px;`

Also there's a couple things you don't need:
`vertical-align: middle;`
`height: 106px;`

Answer (score 0):

I would just flex it. Works for text, but can just as easily take an SVG icon.

```css
.circle {
    font-size: 4.42em;
    font-weight: 300;
    width: 106px;
    height: 106px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #000000;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8.73px 0.27px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.39);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">+</div>
```